# Dagger 2 subcomponents vs component dependencies

Tags: dagger, dagger-2

Dagger 1's `plus()` method is something I used quite often in previous applications, so I understand situations where you might want to have a subcomponent with full access to the parent graphs bindings.

In what situation would it be beneficial to use a *component dependency* instead of a *subcomponent dependency* and why?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

***Component dependencies - Use this when you want to keep two components independent.***

***Subcomponents - Use this when you want to keep two components coupled.***

---

I will use the below example to explain **Component dependencies** and **Subcomponents**. Some points worth noticing about the example are:

- `SomeClassA1` can be created without any dependency. `ModuleA` provides and instance of `SomeClassA1` via the `provideSomeClassA1()` method.
- `SomeClassB1` cannot be created without `SomeClassA1`. `ModuleB` can provide an instance of `SomeClassB1` only if an instance of `SomeClassA1` is passed as an argument to `provideSomeClassB1()` method.

```java
@Module
public class ModuleA {
    @Provides
    public SomeClassA1 provideSomeClassA1() {
        return new SomeClassA1();
    }
}

@Module
public class ModuleB {
    @Provides
    public SomeClassB1 provideSomeClassB1(SomeClassA1 someClassA1) {
        return new SomeClassB1(someClassA1);
    }
}

public class SomeClassA1 {
    public SomeClassA1() {}
}

public class SomeClassB1 {
    private SomeClassA1 someClassA1;

    public SomeClassB1(SomeClassA1 someClassA1) {
        this.someClassA1 = someClassA1;
    }
}
```

Dagger will take care of passing the instance of `SomeClassA1` as an argument to `provideSomeClassB1()` method on `ModuleB` whenever the Component/Subcomponent declaring `ModuleB` is initialized. We need to instruct Dagger how to fulfill the dependency. This can be done either by using **Component dependency** or **Subcomponent**.

### Component dependency

Note the following points in the Component dependency example below:

- `ComponentB` has to define the dependency via the `dependencies` method on `@Component` annotation.
- `ComponentA` doesn't need to declare `ModuleB`. This keeps the two components independent.

```java
public class ComponentDependency {
    @Component(modules = ModuleA.class)
    public interface ComponentA {
        SomeClassA1 someClassA1();
    }

    @Component(modules = ModuleB.class, dependencies = ComponentA.class)
    public interface ComponentB {
        SomeClassB1 someClassB1();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModuleA moduleA = new ModuleA();
        ComponentA componentA = DaggerComponentDependency_ComponentA.builder()
                .moduleA(moduleA)
                .build();

        ModuleB moduleB = new ModuleB();
        ComponentB componentB = DaggerComponentDependency_ComponentB.builder()
                .moduleB(moduleB)
                .componentA(componentA)
                .build();
    }
}
```

### SubComponent

Note the following points in the SubComponent example:

- As `ComponentB` has not defined the dependency on `ModuleA`, it cannot live independently. It becomes dependent on the component that will provide the `ModuleA`. Hence it has a `@Subcomponent` annotation.
- `ComponentA` has declared `ModuleB` via the interface method `componentB()`. This makes the two components coupled. In fact, `ComponentB` can only be initialized via `ComponentA`.

```java
public class SubComponent {
    @Component(modules = ModuleA.class)
    public interface ComponentA {
        ComponentB componentB(ModuleB moduleB);
    }

    @Subcomponent(modules = ModuleB.class)
    public interface ComponentB {
        SomeClassB1 someClassB1();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModuleA moduleA = new ModuleA();
        ComponentA componentA = DaggerSubComponent_ComponentA.builder()
                .moduleA(moduleA)
                .build();

        ModuleB moduleB = new ModuleB();
        ComponentB componentB = componentA.componentB(moduleB);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a subcomponent setup that does not add Module B to ComponentA , which then means that the componentA builder does not need moduleB.  This seems to work the way I expected allowing creation of ComponentA on application start and then instantiating m

Comment: I dont believe you need ModuleB declared in annotation of ComponentA.  This way you can instantiate ComponentA on application start and then create scoped ComponentBs for example per request or per activity. Seems to work very similar to how "plusing" worked in Dagger1

Comment: @MikeN - Can you highlight how you could get rid of ModuleB on ComponentA? I can get rid of ModuleB on ComponentA only if I provide different scopes on ComponentA and ComponentB.

Comment: You're right my setup works because they are on different scopes.  apologies.

Comment: "`SomeClassB1` is dependent on `SomeClassA1`. `ComponentA` has to explicitly define the dependency." ==> have you meant "`ComponentB` has to explicitly define the dependency" ?

Comment: Similarly to what @Tar pointed, I understand that in "`SomeClassB1` is dependent on `SomeClassA1`. `ComponentA` need not explicitly define the dependency." you meant "`ComponentB` need not explicitly define the dependency."

Comment: @Tar @sebas-lg - you are right. I meant `ComponentB`. I have updated the answer with your suggestions. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Also "`ComponentA` has to declare `ModuleB`" seems to be some kind of mistake. I don't see anything like it in code.

Comment: @arekolek - Please see `@Component(modules = ModuleB.class, dependencies = ComponentA.class)` under class `ComponentDependency`

Comment: @PraveerGupta: I think you mentioned "Component Dependency" example, but it should be "SubComponent" example.

Comment: @akashPatra - If you are talking in reference to my reply to @arekolek, you are right. @arekolek - I have made edits to make it more clear that `ComponentA` declared dependency on `ModuleB` via its interface method `componentB()`.

Comment: what happens if I have first implementation but I have scopes too, and I want to pass to the second approach?

Answer (score 50):

According to the [documentation](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html):

`Component Dependency` gives you access to only the bindings exposed as provision methods through component dependencies, i.e. you have access to only types which are declared in parent `Component`.

`SubComponent` gives you an access to the *entire* binding graph from its parent when it is declared, i.e. you have an access to all objects declared in its `Module`s.

Let's say, you have an `ApplicationComponent` containing all `Android` related stuff (`LocationService`, `Resources`, `SharedPreference`, etc). You also want to have your `DataComponent` where you manage things for persistence along with `WebService` to deal with APIs. The only thing you lack in `DataComponent` is `Application Context` which resides in `ApplicationComponent`. The simplest way to get a `Context` from `DataComponent` would be a dependency on `ApplicationComponent`. You need to be sure you have a `Context` explicitly declared in `ApplicationComponent` because you only have access to declared stuff. In this case, there is no manual work, meaning you don't need to specify `Submodules` in parent `Component` and explicitly add your submodule to a parent module like:

```
MySubcomponent mySubcomponent = myComponent.plus(new ChildGraphModule("child!")); // No need!
```

Now consider that case where you want to inject `WebService` from `DataComponent` and `LocationService` from `ApplicationComponent` into your `Fragment` which binds using the `@Submodule` `plus` feature above. The cool thing here is that the component you're binding to (`ApplicationComponent`) does *not* need to expose `WebService` nor `LocationService` because you have access to the entire graph right away.

Comment: If I understand correctly, there is no interface called `@Submodule`. Is it a typo?

Comment: I like how this uses a real life example to showcase the difference.  However, this is more confusing than reading the docs.  It would help to have less `classes` as examples and more pictures to illustrate the exact point.

Answer (score 22):

Here is the code example with screenshot for more understanding of Component and SubComponent:

**Component:**
[image]

1. AppComponent contains two declarations.
2. AppComponent initializes into App class.
3. HomeActivityComponent is dependent upon AppComponent.
4. In HomeActivity on initialization of DaggerHomeActivityComponent, I am giving AppComponent object as a composition.

**SubComponent:**

[image]

1. AppComponent contains SubComponent or SubComponents.
2. AppComponent initializes into App class.
3. SubComponent doesn’t know about his ParentComponent. That only providing its own dependencies by including Module.
4. In HomeActivity I am injecting SubComponent by using its Parent Component.

**And the Pictorial Diagram:**
[image]

Source: [link](http://www.uwanttolearn.com/android/dagger-2-caution-please-try-home-part-5/)

Comment: Wouldn't the diagram make more sense if the subcomponent enclosed the AppComponent?

Answer (score 1):

One other thing that I didn't quite realize until now is that:

- A `@Subcomponent` instance has exactly one parent component (although different components can instantiate that same `@Subcomponent` and be that instance's parent)
- A `@Component` may have zero, one, or many "parent" components declared through [component dependencies](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#dependencies--)

Comment: Probably in second case it isn't correct to say '@Component' may have... parent(s). Rather '@Component' has no parents, but other may be dependent on that (simply use it) via component dependencies.

Comment: @demaksee I don't know, it seems to me that if you map out your component hierarchy, you'll get at DAG, and I think it's a standard way to refer to this relation as parent-child in graph context. If we're talking about the inner workings of Dagger, then I guess it might not be the right word.