# @Component / @SubComponent

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

what's the difference between @component  & @SubComponent in dagger2?
When to use which one of those?

Can you provide examples / code / github or ebook? thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: reviewed my own question, thanks @JFPicard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is duplicate of another question. In fact, SubComponent do have a dependency on the Component in dagger, and can't leave without the component.

This is realted to this post : 
[Dagger 2 subcomponents vs component dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587130/dagger-2-subcomponents-vs-component-dependencies).