# Dagger 2 components chain dependencies

Tags: android, dependency-injection, components, dagger-2

I have 3 components:
Main app component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, UserModule.class, DatabaseModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    Context getContext();

    DatabaseHelper getDatabaseHelper();

    UserManager getUserManager();
}
```

Repository component:

```
@DataScope
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class, modules = CategoryRepositoryModule.class)
public interface CategoryRepositoryComponent {
    CategoryRepository getCategoryRepository();
}
```

And screen component:

```
@MenuScope
@Component(dependencies = CategoryRepositoryComponent.class, modules = {MenuModule.class, DrawerModule.class})
interface MenuComponent {
    void inject(MenuActivity activity);
}
```

The problem is that my MenuComponent cannot see dependencies that provides AppComponent. But MenuComponent depend on CategoryRepositoryComponent and CategoryRepositoryComponent depend on AppComponent, so MenuComponent should see AppComponent(MenuComponent -> CategoryRepositoryComponent -> AppComponent).

If I will add getters to CategoryRepositoryComponent

```
@DataScope
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class, modules = CategoryRepositoryModule.class)
public interface CategoryRepositoryComponent {
    CategoryRepository getCategoryRepository();

    DatabaseHelper getDatabaseHelper();

    UserManager getUserManager();
}
```

But thats looks incorrect, duplicates. Do you know how to resolve this problem in a clean, correct way?

Thanks, 
Nick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is correct. Components only have access to the types explicitly exposed by their direct parent component.

This can be useful when, as a parent, you don't want to expose all of your dependencies to whoever depends on you. For example, a `Parent` may depend on a BankComponent and not want to expose `BankAccount` to its `Children`.

An alternative approach is to use `Subcomponent`. The docs and this other answer will help understand: [Dagger 2 subcomponents vs component dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587130/dagger-2-subcomponents-vs-component-dependencies).

Comment: is totally correct, here you can find a sample project using subcomponents: http://github.com/mmirhoseini/fyber_mobile_offers