# Dagger 2: Provide same instance between multiple Component with same Scope on different library modules

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I have a Core Android Library where I'm defining a CoreComponent ad using the @Singleton scope to inject instances of classes provided by a CoreModule.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {CoreModule.class})
public interface CoreComponent {
    void inject(SomeClass target);
}

@Module
public class CoreModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    CoreRepository provideCoreRepository() {
        return new CoreRepositoryImpl();
    }
}
```

I would like to access the same @Singleton instances from another Android Library that is depending on the Core Library and is using another component.

```
@Singleton
@FooScope
@Component(modules = {CoreModule.class, FooModule.class})
public interface FooComponent {
    void inject(SomeActivity target);
}

public class FooActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject
    public CoreRepository repo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        injectDependencies();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    [...]
}
```

The code above builds but the @Singleton scope is "local" to the Component. In other words there are two singleton instances, one for the for the CoreComponent and one for the FooComponent.

```
Android Application
├── Foo Library
|   └── Core Library
├── Bar Library
|   └── Core Library
·
·
·
└── Core Library
```

I think that the best solution should be using a Subcomponent but, unfortunately, doesn't seem possible because the Core Library has no visibility of the other libraries.

Is there another way to share with Dagger the same instance of one class between components if the class is annotated with the same Scope?

Comment: Have you looked into [component dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29587130/1426891) yet? See [Javadoc](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#component-dependencies) here and note that you may need to explicitly expose some extra accessor methods on your CoreComponent so that FooComponent can call them.

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036933/how-to-set-up-dagger-dependency-injection-from-scratch-in-android-project which has an example of using scopes and dependent components

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Remove the injection sites from your `CoreComponent` - it now has the sole function of exposing the binding for `CoreRepository` to its dependent components:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {CoreModule.class})
public interface CoreComponent {
    CoreRepository coreRepository();
}
```

Create a reference to this singleton-scoped component inside your application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private final CoreComponent coreComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        coreComponent = DaggerCoreComponent
                            .coreModule(new CoreModule())
                            .build();
    }

    public static CoreComponent getCoreComponent(Context context) {
        return ((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).coreComponent;
    }
}
```

Create a new narrower scope:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) public @interface PerActivity {}
```

Create a new component that tracks this scope complete with the injection sites you want:

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = {CoreComponent.class})
public interface ActivityComponent {
    void inject(FooActivity activity);

    void inject(BarActivity activity);
}
```

When you access this activity-scoped component in the injection site, you will need to provide the instance of `CoreComponent` to the builder. Now you can inject into your `Activity`

```
public class FooActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Inject
        public CoreRepository repo;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            CoreComponent coreComponent = MyApplication.getCoreComponent(this);
            DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                .coreComponent(coreComponent)
                .build()
                .inject(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed! The only thing that I'm doing differently is also keeping the inject methods in the CoreComponent because I also need to inject the CoreRepository inside the Core Library. Is that not nice? Should I create a new Component with dependency to it to use inside the Core Library and leave the CoreComponent without any inject?

Comment: Depends on the scope you want for the dependencies in CoreLibrary. If you only want app singletons inside then its probably okay. However I personally like to have components that track the scope of their injection sites

Comment: One more question: as far as I know I cannot have more then one scoped dependency for one Component, is there a way to get it to work with multiple scoped dependencies? For example I have multiple libraries, each with a @Singleton scoped Component and I would like to be able to share the singleton instances with my ActivityComponent. The libraries are independent and don't see each other.

Comment: @RobertoLeinardi you can have a top-level component with a medium-level dependent component with a low-level dependent component - if that's unclear, maybe post a new question and someone can answer it.

Comment: @RobertoLeinardi could you help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953373/dagger-getting-same-instance-on-different-component? I'm having difficulty implementing this.

Comment: Thank you, really helped me to start to understand how scopes work