# Dagger - Getting Same Instance On Different Component

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm having a similar problem like the one in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745279/dagger-2-provide-same-instance-between-multiple-component-with-same-scope-on-di) question.
While the accepted answer does help, but I'm missing final piece to solve the problem.

I have 2 android library modules: `common` and `exp` which depends on `common`.

Everything under `common`:

```
@Module
public class CommonModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Repository providesRepository() {
        return new Repository();
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules={CommonModule.class})
public interface CommonComponent {
    void inject(CommonClass commonClass);
    /**
        CommonClass needs instance of Repository
    **/
}

public class CommonDIHolder {
    public static CommonComponent sComponent;

    public static void init() {
        sComponent = DaggerCommonComponent.builder().build();
    }
}
```

Everything under `exp`:

```
@Module(includes={CommonModule.class})
public class ExpModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public ExpResource provideExpResource() {
        return new ExpResource();
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules={ExpModule.class}, dependencies={CommonComponent.class})
public interface ExpComponent {
    void inject(ExpClass expClass); 
    /**
        ExpClass needs instance of Repository and ExpResource
    **/
}

public class ExpDIHolder {
    public static ExpComponent sComponent;

    public static void init() {
        sComponent = DaggerExpComponent.builder()
                            .commonComponent(CommonDIHolder.sComponent)
                            .build();
    }
}
```

I need both `CommonClass` and `ExpClass` receive the same instance of `Repository`.

The problem with this approach is that `@Singleton` can't depends on `@Singleton`. So I have to change the scope of `ExpComponent` into self-defined scope called `@ExpScope`. Then I changed the `provideExpResource` into `@ExpScope` as well.

Then I encountered an error saying that `ExpComponent` may not reference bindings with different scopes. It refers to the `provideRepository` which has different scope (`@Singleton`) on it. If I changed the scope into `ExpScope` then the `CommonComponent` will have different scope with `provideRepository`.

If I changed all `@Singleton` into `@ExpScope` then I receive this error message: `depends on scoped components in a non-hierarchical scope ordering`

What should I do? Or I'm doing the wrong approach here?

Comment: "So I have to change the scope of ExpComponent into self-defined scope called **ExpScope**. Then I changed the provideExpResource into **ExpScope** as well" Works normally with this setup. Using dagger 2.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use one and only one `@Singleton` scoped component**

You should have one and only one `@Singleton` scoped component like this:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={CommonModule.class, ExpModule.class})
public interface CommonComponent {

}
```

**Only specify Activities, Fragments, and Services as explicit injection targets for Components**

In an Android app, you should only list Activities, Fragments and Services as injection sites. You should configure Dagger 2 to inject the rest of your dependencies without having to resort to calling `component.inject(this)` inside them.

For example, if your `CommonClass` looks like this:

```
public class CommonClass {
    @Inject Repository repository;

    public class CommonClass() {
         CommonComponentHolder.get().inject(this);
    }
}
```

Refactor it like this:

```
public class CommonClass {
    private final Repository repository;

    @Inject
    public class CommonClass(Repository repository) {
         this.repository = repository;
    }
}
```

Now when you have an Activity or Fragment that needs `CommonClass` and you are injecting with `CommonComponent` or one of its sub-components or dependent components, they can obtain instances of `CommonClass` wired with the correct dependencies:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject CommonClass commonClass;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        CommonComponentHolder.getComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

**Use subcomponents or dependent components to specify the injection targets**

Now you have a `@Singleton` scoped component, you'll probably want to create a component for a narrower scope for your Activity or Fragment. You'll have to connect it to your `CommonComponent`, so use dependent components or subcomponents (subcomponents are preferred as of Dagger 2.10). Since you say you have already tried defining a `@ExpScope`, I think the missing piece is to make subcomponent or dependent component with the `@ExpScope` that injects your Activity or Fragment.

Something like the following for the top-level singleton component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={CommonModule.class, ExpModule.class})
public interface CommonComponent {
    ExpComponent.Builder exComponent();
}
```

And then for the subcomponent:

```
@ExpScope
@Subcomponent(modules = {NarrowerScopedModule.class})
public interface ExpComponent {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    public interface Builder {
        Builder narrowerScopedModule(NarrowerScopedModule narrowerScopedModule);
        ExpComponent build();
    }
}
```

There are good working examples of Android projects in the [Google Android Architecture Blueprints Github repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture)

Comment: `CommonComponent` can't have reference to `ExpModule` since `exp` depends on `common`, not the other way around. Does this means I have to create one in the most top level (that depends on both `exp` and `common`) which job is to build the component?

Comment: @AhmadFadli create one component at the singleton level. Bind all the modules of app-scoped (singleton) dependencies there. Then create different sub-components at the level of the activity or fragments with the modules for the scopes of the activity or fragments

Comment: Ok, but how to get the reference to the subcomponent in each activities? Since the activities doesn't have access to top level component. I'm thinking of creating a singleton class in each android modules to store the subcomponent which has been constructed in top level component. Any other way?

Comment: @AhmadFadli initialize the subcomponent inside the activity inside the `onCreate` method. Don't "store" any of the subcomponents anywhere.

Comment: @AhmadFadli please accept my answer if it was useful to you :)

Comment: the subComponent for `exp` will be used in more than 1 activities. In 1 module android application, I would store the component inside the Application class, but since it's on different modules I have to create a similar singleton class, or not?

Comment: @AhmadFadli don't persist the subcomponents - they should be created inside the `onCreate()` and destroyed when the Activity lifecycle finishes. If you need dependencies that persist from Activity to Activity then these are app-scoped singletons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138788/discussion-between-ahmad-fadli-and-david-rawson).