# SubComponents vs Component dependencies

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I read difference between `SubComponents` and `Component Dependencies` from this docs https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html and read this thread too [Dagger 2 subcomponents vs component dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587130/dagger-2-subcomponents-vs-component-dependencies)

Can anyone help me for what this line means with an example .

> SubComponents may use any binding defined by their ancestor component and subcomponents. as an alternative, components can use bindings only from another component interface by declaring a component dependency. When a type is used as a component dependency, each provision method on the dependency is bound as a provider. Note that only the bindings exposed as provision methods are available through component dependencies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think of it as a subcomponent like java `SubComponent extends ParentComponent` where everything is `protected`. It will have access to the same members as the parent and can just use all of the parents things.

A component dependency on the other hand is like a delegate object, where you only have access to the public methods that the class exposes.

---

Lets just assume we have 2 classes that Dagger can create and provide. Whatever this might be. It does not matter if you use constructor injection or create the objects from a module...We just assume we have those 2 classes that can be provided by some `BaseComponent`, which I will show next.

```
// some module can create either object
class ComponentPrivateObject {}
class ExposedObject {}
```

It does not matter where they come from. The next part is the interesting bit. We declare *one* of those classes as a return type on a method on our component interface. This is what Dagger calls a *Provision Method*. It says that this component can provide that class.

```
@Component(modules=/* some modules */)
class BaseComponent {

  // BaseComponent can provide ExposedObject!
  ExposedObject exposedObject();

}
```

The difference between subcomponent and dependent component is that, as with the java sample in the beginning, `Subcomponent` will have access to both `ComponentPrivateObject` and `ExposedObject` because it just *extends* the parents graph.

```
// can use either class, it just adds to the parent
@Subcomponent
class Subcomponent {}
```

On the other hand, `DependentComponent` only has access to `ExposedObject`. It does not extend the graph of `BaseComponent`, but it just binds `BaseComponent` as a provider for some objects. Like with the java sample above, its like using its public API, and if you try to use `ComponentPrivateObject` Dagger will tell you that it *cannot be provided...*

```
// binds component dependency as provider
@Component(dependency=BaseComponent.class)
class DependentComponent{}
```

One extends the parent, the other one uses its public API.

Comment: Please don't "Think of it as a subcomponent like java SubComponent extends ParentComponent".  There is no inheritance relationship between components and subcomponents.  Rather, think of them like inner classes (they are implemented that way) in that you get access to everything from the enclosing component.

Comment: Aside from the previous comment, this is a great explanation!