# Dagger 2 extending interfaces vs dependent components

Tags: dagger-2

In `Dagger` I sometimes see that there are components that just extend an interface while others use the `dependencies`.

So for example we have a base component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={...})
public interface BaseComponent {
    ...
}
```

Version 1:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={...})
public interface MyComponent extends BaseComponent {
    ...
}
```

And Version 2:

```
@CustomScope
@Component(modules={...}, dependencies= BaseComponent.class)
public interface MyComponent {
    ...
}
```

Are they used for different scenarios?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a hierarchy of components, the standard ways to do this are to use [subcomponents](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents) or to use [dependent components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587130/dagger-2-subcomponents-vs-component-dependencies).

You can use interface extension to make test components. This is a better solution than extending modules. See [here](https://google.github.io/dagger/testing) for an explanation from the official docs:

```
@Component(modules = {
  OAuthModule.class, // real auth
  FooServiceModule.class, // real backend
  OtherApplicationModule.class,
  /* … */ })
interface ProductionComponent {
  Server server();
}

@Component(modules = {
  FakeAuthModule.class, // fake auth
  FakeFooServiceModule.class, // fake backend
  OtherApplicationModule.class,
  /* … */})
interface TestComponent extends ProductionComponent {
  FakeAuthManager fakeAuthManager();
  FakeFooService fakeFooService();
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say those member injectors in ComponentB are necessarily undesirable. This is how you'd use ComponentB in testing. See `Option 2: Separate component configurations` in docs: https://google.github.io/dagger/testing